# Would a [tubemate] tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

TubeMate is an Android video download app. Its website is http://tubemate.net/ and it's been around and maintained for many years (the website for TubeMate has been around since 2011 according to archive.org, making the website 11 years old).

There are 23 search results for "TubeMate" on Android.SE, and it seems the most relevant tags we currently have is [download-manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download-manager) and possibly [youtube](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) (because YouTube is the most popular website supported by TubeMate, and presumably where TubeMate gets its name from).

Would a [tubemate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tubemate)  tag would be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *tags are for questions* but not the answers, as of current writing, actually there are only [3 questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=tubemate+is%3Aq) specifically about TubeMate.

However, with the popularity of the app and its unambiguous meaning, I don't see an issue with creating it.

**[tubemate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tubemate) tag created**.